# React - update <select> when <option> updated

Tags: reactjs, typescript3.0

I have made a simple component to fill `<select>` with array of entries either from REST or local array. The code is used as follows:

```
<ComboBox id="TestAsync" label="Country List" default="DE" onChange={this.change}>
    <DataSource source="/api/region/country" idField="id" captionField="name" />
</ComboBox>
```

`<ComboBox>` is basically a statement with select, but with `<DataSource>` detection. Below is `<ComboBox>` render code

```
constructor(props: IField) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: props.default
    }
}

public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: IField, prevStat: IState) {
    if (prevProps.default != this.props.default) this.setState({ value: this.props.default });
}

render() {
    return <div className="hx-field" id={this.props.id}>
        <label>{this.props.label}</label>
        <select name={this.props.id} onChange={this.onChangeSelect.bind(this)} value={this.state.value} disabled={this.props.readonly} key={this.props.id}>
            {this.props.children}
        </select>
    </div>
}
```

And this is `<Datasource>` class:

```
export class DataSource extends React.Component<IDataSource, IDataSourceState> {

    constructor(props: IDataSource<T>) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rawData: null,
            options: [
                <option value="">Loading ... </option>
            ]
        }
    }

    private option(item): JSX.Element {
        return <option value={item[this.props.idField]} key={item[this.props.idField]}>{item[this.props.captionField]}</option>
    }

    private load() {
        Adapter.load(this.props)
            .then(result => {
                if (!result) return;
                this.setState({
                    rawData: result,
                    options: result.map(x => this.option(x))
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("DataSource load error: Cannot load REST data");
                console.error(error);
            })
    }

    public render() {
        return this.state.options;
    }
}
```

The code is working, with one exception. I can't send a default value to it. The problem I think when that `<select>` component's value rendered, datasource is still empty. But the code works fine when I send value AFTER datasource populated. i.e picking an option from combobox.

How to force update `<select>` component when `<datasource>` modified?

Comment: How are you using the `default` prop?

Comment: `this.state = {value: this.props.default}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is using `selected` prop on `<option>`:

```
export class DataSource extends React.Component<IDataSource, IDataSourceState> {
//    ...
  private option(item): JSX.Element {
     const {idField, captionField} = this.props;
     const {[idField]: id, [captionField]: caption} = item;
     return 
        <option 
           value={id} 
           key={id}
           selected={id===this.props.value}
        >
        {caption}
        </option>
   }
```

This way we need pass actual `value` into `DataSource` otherwise our default value will never be changed:

```
<ComboBox id="TestAsync" label="Country List" onChange={this.changeCountryListValue}>
    <DataSource source="/api/region/country" idField="id" captionField="name" selected={this.countryListValue || 'DE'} />
</ComboBox>
```

Or you can make your `ComboBox` to modify nested `DataSource` with injecting either `onLoad` callback or providing `selected` value like I did above in direct way. `React.children.map` and `React.cloneElement` [to rescue on that](https://mxstbr.blog/2017/02/react-children-deepdive/#changing-children-props).

And finally you can move all the loading data out the `ComboBox` to either parent element or to some wrapper. I'd rather follow this way since currently your generic-named `DataSource` both loading data and rendering items into `<option>` that breaks single responsibility principle. This might disallow you using that in different context(when say you need load the same data but display in different component rather `<option>`)

Comment: LOL. Yes.. that would be my second question actually. My goal with `<DataSource>` is actually to render any data fed to it, into multiple components with same template, Its source can be a URL, a data adapter, or an Array variable. And I also wonder, how to render those data into component other than option. But I will make another question for that if I can't find a way. 

I think I'll go with injecting `onLoad`. that should be cleaner. Thank you